# Quickest way to get elements given matrix of indices in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I have an N by 2 matrix A of indices of elements I want to get from a 2D matrix B, each row of A being the row and column index of an element of B that I want to get. I would like to get all of those elements stacked up as an N by 1 vector.

B is a square matrix, so I am currently using

```
N = size(B,1);
indices = arrayfun(@(i) A(i,1) + N*(A(i,2)-1), 1:size(A,1));
result = B(indices);
```

but, while it works, this is probing to be a **huge** bottleneck and I need to speed up the code in order for it to be useful.

What is the fastest way I can achieve the same result?

Comment: BTW, it is [best not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: I had come across that, but it's a habit that's hard to kill after many years of C++... besides, everything I am currently working on is exclusively using numbers in R :)

Comment: @Shai: I would be less of a loosing battle if you tell people to stop using `i` for complex numbers and use `1i` instead :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
indices = [1 N] * (A'-1) + 1;
```

Comment: Words can't do justice to how thankful I am. Elegant, concise and *efficient*!

Comment: always +1 for matrix multiplication

Answer (score 0):

I can never remember if `B(A(:,1), A(:,2))` works the way you want it to, but I'd try that to avoid the intermediate variable.  If that does not work, try `subs2ind`.

Also, you can look at how you generated `A` in the first place.  if `A` came about from the output of find, for example, it is faster to use logical indexing.  i.e if

```
B( B == 2 )
```

Is faster than finding the row,col indexes that satisfy that condition, then indexing into `B`.

Comment: I had tried sub2ind previously, and it took some 10times longer than my arrayfun solution :/ Logical indexing is also not an option in this case